# Iframe returns 404

Tags: wordpress, iframe, themes, http-status-code-404

I created my very first wordpress theme but i have a problem with iframe.
in wordpress I use "iframe" plugin with this shortcode:

```
[iframe
border="0"
name="iframe"
src="http://www.parshid.com/projects/bide-majnun/first.php"
width="100%"
height="800px"
scrolling="no"
frameborder="0"
onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';"]
```

it worked just fine but now with my new theme it returns "404 - Not Found" error.

thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't add the line breaks, that's your problem.

```
[iframe border="0" name="iframe" src="http://www.parshid.com/projects/bide-majnun/first.php" width="100%" height="800px" scrolling="no" frameborder="0" onload="document.getElementById('loadImg').style.display='none';"]
```

Once you do that it works perfectly for me.

Comment: thanks dude! it worked but do you have any idea why that code worked just fine the way i wrote before? @michaelrmcneill

Comment: @Zartosht no idea why it worked before and stopped working. All I could see was if I put the line breaks, it didn't work. Sorry I can't give a reason, but glad it works!

Comment: I have no such line breaks but get this problem so the underlying cause must be something else.